# How to handle searchbar onchangetext event from navigation in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I want to make a search activity in react-native. I create a stacknavigation in tabBottomNavigator and stacknavigation has navigation options and headerLeft options. I have ,  and  components. My question is about how to handle searchbar onchangetext event from  component even it is in a diffrent class. Thanks...

StackForSearch.js

```
export default createStackNavigator({ Search:{ screen: Search,
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) =>({
  headerLeft: <SearchHeader navigation={navigation}/>,
  }),
},});
```

SearchHeader.js

```
export default class SearchHeader extends Component<{}>{


  render(){

    return(
      <View style={styles.Container} >
      <SearchBar
        containerStyle={{backgroundColor:'white', margin:0,padding:0,borderWidth:0,borderBottomWidth:0}}
        inputStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white',paddingLeft:36,fontSize:16,color:'#171F33'}}
        lightTheme
        round
        onChangeText={}
        icon={{style:{color:'black', fontSize:22 ,margin:0}}}
        placeholder='Search..' />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Container:{
    flex:1
  }
});
```

Search.js - I want to handle the onChangeText event in Search.js

```
export default class Search extends Component<{}>{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){

    return(
      <View style={styles.Container}>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Container:{
    flex:1,
  },
  StatusBar:{
    marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor:'#171F33'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `onChangeText` from `SearchBar` on your `SearchHeader.js` get fired everytime the Text changes. so you could pass to `onChangeText` property another function that is passed from `Search.js` as a props.

1. Add `onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText}` in your `SearchHeader.js`
2. Create an arrow function in your `Search.js` and pass it as a props to the `SearchHeader.js` component:

   ```
    export default class Search extends Component<{}>{    
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
      }

      onChangeText = (newText) => {
        //your custom logic here
        console.log(newText);
      }

      render(){    
       return(
        <View style={styles.Container}>
         <SearchHeader 
           onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
         />
        </View>
       );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      Container:{
       flex:1,
      },
     StatusBar:{
      marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : Constants.statusBarHeight,
      backgroundColor:'#171F33'
     }
   });
   ```